# Look up the refund amount given a payment intent via Stripe's API

Tags: stripe-payments

How can I look up the amount refunded for a given payment intent in Stripe via API call?

Let's say I have a payment intent (`pi_3NnXXYKI47gqqtmf0eR178Es`), how can I check if it has been fully or partially refunded and by how much?

Using the stripe cli, I see there is a `latest_charge` property:

```bash
stripe payment_intents retrieve pi_3NnXXYKI47gqqtmf0eR178Es
```

```json
{
  "id": "pi_3NnXXYKI47gqqtmf0eR178Es",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "amount": 2500,
  "amount_capturable": 0,
  "amount_details": {
    "tip": {}
  },
  "amount_received": 2500,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_amount": 500,
  "automatic_payment_methods": null,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "capture_method": "automatic",
  "client_secret": "pi_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "confirmation_method": "automatic",
  "created": 1694053104,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": "cus_OTWo2r0gDDcyoj",
  "description": null,
  "invoice": "in_1NnXn3KI471qqtmftliLpC1g",
  "last_payment_error": null,
  "latest_charge": "ch_3NuInYKx47gqotmf0Rp7uWyX",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_action": null,
  "on_behalf_of": "acct_1Nm3Xy2eoonJLRTG",
  "payment_method": "pm_10gZ42Kp47gqqtmfT4SWIXKK",
  "payment_method_options": {
    "card": {
      "installments": null,
      "mandate_options": null,
      "network": null,
      "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
    }
  },
  "payment_method_types": [
    "card"
  ],
  "processing": null,
  "receipt_email": "bob@example.com",
  "review": null,
  "setup_future_usage": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "source": null,
  "statement_descriptor": null,
  "statement_descriptor_suffix": null,
  "status": "succeeded",
  "transfer_data": {
    "destination": "acct_1Nm3r22eNoJJVRTG"
  },
  "transfer_group": "group_pi_3NnXnkXI47gqqtmf0eRI78Es"
}
```

I can then look up the "latest charge" via the cli like so:

```bash
stripe charges retrieve ch_3NuInYKx47gqotmf0Rp7uWyX
```

```json
{
  "id": "ch_3NuInYKx47gqotmf0Rp7uWyX",
  "amount_refunded": 1500,
  ...
}
```

Is this approach reliable? Is it possible that the payment intent has a charge that has a refund and is NOT the latest charge? The API documentation was sparse for the [latest_chage property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-latest_charge).

Any pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that the payment intent has a charge that has a refund and is NOT the latest charge?

No, it isn’t possible.
The only reason why a Payment Intent can have multiple charges is because it can have multiple *failed* charges, but it can only have one succeeded one, which would be its latest.

You can only refund succeeded charges, so if a charge was refunded, it can only be the Payment Intent’s latest.

It’s worth mentioning that latest_charge is a rather new attribute for Payment Intents. If for whatever reason you use multiple Stripe accounts for your work, you might not see it if the API version is older than 2022-11-15 (back then it was known as the Intent’s charges array, which still only gave you the latest one despite being an array).

For this reason, the call suggested by @qichuan might be better.

Comment: API change docs for replacing charges with latest_charge: https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-11-15

Comment: I'm having trouble finding supporting Stripe documentation about what you said for the payment intent's latest_charge. This is the closest I could find: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status#identifying-charges

Comment: I don’t think the documentation outlines it. You can understand this mechanic purely from testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds/list#list_refunds) to retrieve all refunds associated with this PaymentIntent to obtain the refund amount.